# Background processing on items in a collection + adding new items (using a thread pool)

Tags: c#, collections, threadpool, background-process

I have an object in my application which performs processing on the items in a collection in a background thread.  When the object is created background processing of all existing items in the collection is triggered using the thread pool:

```
class CollectionProcessor
{
    public CollectionProcessor()
    {
        // Not actually called during the constructor just put it here to simplify the code sample
        Action process = new Action(this.Process);
        createIndex.BeginInvoke(true, ar => process.EndInvoke(ar), null);
    }

    void Process()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < this.items.Count; i++)
        {
            this.ProcessItem(this.items[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

There is some extra code dotted around for notification callbacks but that is largely the gist of it.

New items can be added to this collection at any time and I need to make sure that those new items are processed - notification of new items is provided by an event which is fired after the items have already been added to the collection.  In the event hanlder for this event I need to **asynchronously** resume the processing of the new items in the collection while also:

- Ensuring that I don't process the same item twice
- Ensuring that the items are processed in the correct order
- Avoiding queuing up lots of blocked background tasks

I also want to achieve this using a thread pool instead of using a dedicated thread - **How should I do this?** Obviously assume that access to `this.items` is thread-safe.

Comment: Could you not use a Syncronised Queue<T> and move the objects to your list once processing has started?

Comment: @Lloyd Access to the collection is already thread-safe, my question is more around the pattern I should use when asynchronously calling `Process`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I have figured out a reasonably neat way of doing this.  They key is to note that if I had a dedicated background thread performing this processing then the solution is fairly easy and might look a little like this:

```
AutoResetEvent ev = new AutoResetEvent(false);

// Called on a background thread
void ThreadProc()
{
    int lastProcessed = 0;
    while (true)
    {
        // Perform our processing as before
        for (int i = lastProcessed; i < this.items.Count; i++)
        {
            this.ProcessItem(this.items[i]);
        }

        // We have processed all items currently in the list, wait for some more
        ev.WaitOne();
    }
}

void OnNewItems()
{
    ev.Set();
}
```

The missing link is the [`ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject` Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/02x3daw5%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) which allows us to convert this to using a thread pool instead of a dedicated thread:

```
int lastProcessed = 0;

void StartProcessing()
{
    ThreadPool.RegisterWaitForSingleObject(
        this.ev,
        new WaitOrTimerCallback(WaitProc),
        null,   // All state stored in the class instance itself
        -1,     // Always wait indefinitely for new items
        true    // Only execute once - each callback registers a new wait handle ensuring
                // that a maximum of 1 task is running Process at any one time
    );
}

void WaitProc(object state, bool timedOut)
{
    // Perform our processing as before
    for (int i = lastProcessed; i < this.items.Count; i++)
    {
        this.ProcessItem(this.items[i]);
    }

    // We have processed all items currently in the list, wait for some more
    this.StartProcessing();
}
```

This sets up a loop just as before except we aren't blocking a thread waiting for the reset event.